# AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'pressed'

Tags: python, wxpython

I've tried removing the event parameter in pressed() and shifting the position of pressed() as well, but nothing works...I'm quite stuck.

**My code which i tried :**

```
import wx

class Window ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__ ( self ):
        super().__init__ ( parent = None, title = "Hello World!" )
        
        panel = wx.Panel ( self )
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer ( wx.VERTICAL )
        
        self.TextBox = wx.TextCtrl ( panel, pos = ( 5, 5 ), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_AUTO_URL )
        sizer.Add ( self.TextBox, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        
        self.button = wx.Button ( panel, label = "Button", pos = ( 5, 40 ) )
        self.button.Bind ( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pressed )
        sizer.Add ( self.button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5 )
        
        def pressed ( self, event ):
            text = self.TextBox.GetValue()
            print ( text )
        
        panel.SetSizer ( sizer )
        self.Show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    window = Window()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\Dell\Python\WxPython.py", line 27, in <module>
    window = Window()

  File "E:\Dell\Python\WxPython.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.button.Bind ( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pressed )

AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'pressed'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pressed method is over-indented. It must be on the same level as **init**. Otherwise it would be a function local to the **init**, visible only in **init**, and actually valid after the self.button.Bind call.

```
import wx

class Window ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__ ( self ):
        super().__init__ ( parent = None, title = "Hello World!" )

        panel = wx.Panel ( self )
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer ( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.TextBox = wx.TextCtrl ( panel, pos = ( 5, 5 ), style = wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_AUTO_URL )
        sizer.Add ( self.TextBox, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.button = wx.Button ( panel, label = "Button", pos = ( 5, 40 ) )
        self.button.Bind ( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.pressed )
        sizer.Add ( self.button, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5 )

        panel.SetSizer ( sizer )
        self.Show()

    def pressed ( self, event ):
        text = self.TextBox.GetValue()
        print ( text )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    window = Window()
    app.MainLoop()
```